# Java Eclipse - Credentials Popup on HTTPS GET

Tags: java, eclipse, https, popup, jersey-2.0

I've written a piece of Java code, as part of an Eclipse plugin, that connects to a remote https site. I'm passing my own credentials to the get request, but eclipse keeps throwing a popup asking for credentials on every get request! although it's not even doing anything, since I can hit cancel or enter no credentials, and the get requests returns successfully.

Who can I disable this popup?
I know it's triggered by Eclipse, because of the icon on the window.
I'm using Eclipse version Mars 2 but I'm able to reproduce for Luna too.
[image: The popup I'm getting]

This is my code, I'm using jersey 2.0 API

**Main Code**

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
// set connect timeout
clientConfig.property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 10000);
// set query timeout
clientConfig.property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, 300000);
// register Base Authentication Feature providing credentials
clientConfig.register(HttpAuthenticationFeature.basicBuilder()
            .nonPreemptive()
            .credentials(restUserName, restPassword)
            .build());

ClientBuilder builder = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
                                     .withConfig(clientConfig)
                                     .hostnameVerifier(HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());
// set ssl context
try
{
    builder.sslContext(getSslContext());
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    connectionError = "SSL Handshake Error";
}

// build the REST client
client = builder.build();


// Get Request
Builder builder = this.GetRestTarget().path(String.format("builds/%d", buildId)).request();
Response response = builder.get();
```

**SSL**

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", pathToKeystoreFile);
SslConfigurator sslConfig = SslConfigurator.newInstance();
return sslConfig.createSSLContext();
```